# convert timespan to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

My function is :

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RecentAddedTags(int daysago)
{
    TimeSpan duration = DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.Today.AddDays(-daysago);
    DateTime days = DateTime.UtcNow - duration;
    var ret = from tag in db.Tags
    where tag.time.Equals(days)
    select new
    {
        postedById = tag.AspNetUser.Id,
        postedByName = tag.AspNetUser.UserName,
        name = tag.name,
        info = tag.info,
        time = tag.time,
        id = tag.Id,
    };
    return Ok(ret);
}
```

If I call the function as `RecentAddedTags(2)` it should return all tags created 2 days ago. But it gives the error:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

There is some issue with `days` object. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: does == instead of Equals work ?

Comment: oh my God. It worked !

Comment: If that worked, I'm shocked too! :D

Comment: @sirrocco please write answer and I will accept as right.

Comment: @IrfanWattoo as a side note, it seems the method is broken. This will get tags created two days ago, ***exactly***. Perhaps it should be `where tag.time > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-daysago)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
tag.time.Equals(days)
```

to

```
tag.time == days;
```

(not entirely sure why it works)

Comment: @IrfanWattoo what is the type of the `time` member, and is its `Equals` method overwritten?

Comment: Hmm that might be it, I assumed it would be a datetime object

Comment: From the information question so I would have. But there's got to be something. In any case more than the OP showed us.

Comment: @Christian.K datatype of `time` is `DateTime`

Comment: @IrfanWattoo Hmm... very strange. The implementation of [DateTime.Equals()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,21b491277af0127a,references) is identical to `DateTime.operator==`.

Answer (score 2):

Compare Date in DateTime Object it will work for you

```
    var ret = from tag in db.Tags.ToList()
              where tag.time.Date == days.Date
              select new
              {
                    postedById = tag.AspNetUser.Id,
                    postedByName = tag.AspNetUser.UserName,
                    name = tag.name,
                    info = tag.info,
                    time = tag.time,
                    id = tag.Id,
              };
```